# Ubuntu Server install saying drive is 0mb

Tags: boot, server, partitioning, usb, mount

This is my first time trying to install Ubuntu Server, so please bear with my ignorance on this topic.

When I get to the install where I need to choose a file system, it says that my MicroSD has 0mb of space.  using lsblk I can see that there's a 117gb directory at /dev/sdb4.  I've tried setting readonly to false, remounting the drive as writeable, etc. but the installer can't recognize that there's space on the drive.

I'm trying to run the install on my laptop through a MicroSD to usb adapter and setting it to boot first.  Perhaps the adapter is getting in the way?

I've also tried this with 2 other MicroSD cards with the same exact issue, so I don't think the cards are dead.  Furthermore, I can't even reformat the drives after Ubuntu Server was flashed onto them.

Edit for Clarification: I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server completely on the MicroSD and then transfer it to a libre board so I can set it up as a dedicated server.  I was just running the install using my laptop as the boot device before I transfer it.

Comment: @user535733 Apologies, I will update the post for clarification.  Basically, I'm trying to create a portable microSD with Ubuntu already installed.  However, when the installer gets to the "choose disk for file system" step it shows the MicroSD as 0mb.  It lists my Laptop SSD as an available drive with space, but I don't want to install it on that drive.  I'm trying to transfer the microSD to a libre so I can set it up as a server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Install Ubuntu on MicroSD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1126409/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-microsd)